# How can I copy a folder from my machine to another machine from command line?

Tags: networking, file-transfer

I have tried :-

c:>xcopy  \192.168.1.12\Share\IT\

But it copies only files not the folders.

Comment: I'd assume this is windows? What version?

Comment: Which folders did it omit? Have a read http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

`xcopy /e \\192.168.1.12\Share\IT\`

The `/e` will copy all folders and sub folders. You can replace it with `/s` if you want empty folders and sub folders to be ignored.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289483 has more information on the switches available for both xcopy and xcopy32.